# How could I forbid manual updates of a specific object attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My class has a column `secret` which I generate using a specific process. Because of this, I don't want to let the user update this field via an edit form.
However, if the user adds manually the `secret` tag to the form and submit it, my object's `secret` gets updated too.

```
def update
  object.attributes = params[:my_class]
end
```

I guess I create a before filter like this one

```
before_filter :clear_secret, :only => :update
def clear_secret
  params.delete(:secret)
end
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this. Could I do this from the model? Is there a already existing Rails method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Rails 3, you can protect this via `attr_protected`

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :secret
end
```

A user attempting to inject a `secret` field into the form will instead cause Rails to raise a `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error`.

However, this mechanism is deprecated in Rails 4 in favor of the strong_parameters mechanism referenced by @gylaz.

Comment: I see it working on Rails 2 but it does not raise any error. Was this behavior added from Rails 3?

Comment: Yes, it existed in Rails 2.

Comment: No, I think that in Rails 2 it just silently eats protected attributes.

Answer (score 2):

It's conventional to use [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem to do this.

Using said gem you can permit only the attributes that can be updated, like this:

```
params.permit(:some_attr, :another_attr)
```